# How to get exact PresentingViewController when Modal View dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, segue, uistoryboard

My App navigation is like below:

> NavigationController ---> RootViewController --(Show Segue)-> SomeViewController --(Show Segue)-> ParentViewController (With ContainerView)

So, ParentViewController has a container view.
This container view is populated programmatically, at runtime, depending upon user selection.
So, basically the view hierarchy is like this:

> ParentViewController (With ContainerView) ---(Embed Segue) --> ContainerViewController --(Custom Segue, for deciding which child to show at runtime) --->
>   FirstChildViewController/SecondChildViewController

Now, I display a modal view when a button is tapped in SecondChildViewController. Everything is fine, till this point.

But, now I want to update data in SecondChildViewController on the dismissal of ModalViewController. I try to do it like this in ModalViewController:

```
SecondChildViewController *secondChildVC = (SecondChildViewController *)self.presentingViewController;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: ^{ [secondChildVC updateList];   }];
```

But, I am getting following error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController
>   updateList]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x127e451b0'

How can I fix this issue? So, to be specific, how can I get the "real" presentingViewController? I know its a bit weird navigation, and there is too much stacking on views from user experience point of view, but that is the way client wants to implement.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly. If you have a ViewController A, presenting ViewController B, and if you wish to call a method in A when B is dismissed - you can make A a delegate of B.

Read more about Protocols and Delegates here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, but you got it almost right. I know I can always go for Protocols/delegate mechanism. But, this problem is not very uncommon. Instead of SecondChildViewController instance, I am getting UINavigationViewController instance, as the presentingViewController. Is there any way to find out the "real" presentingViewController? Thanks for your reply!!

Comment: Try UINavigationViewController.topViewController

Comment: Nope... that does will give me ParentViewController and again will have to look for its child. I have implemented the delegate pattern as of now.